# Kano OS with BerryBoot

Tags: berryboot

Is it possible to run Kano OS from BerryBoot? My son plays with [Kano OS](http://www2.kano.me/downloads). I would also like to run Raspbian and OpenElec from the same SD-card.

I believe Kano-OS is based on Raspbian, so it should be able to boot from BerryBoot.

I appreciate if you can let me know how to do it.

Comment: I found this article here ->.
http://www.howtogeek.com/141325/how-to-multi-boot-your-raspberry-pi-with-berryboot/

I will try to create an image of Kano OS, and add to BerryBoot later on.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I found Kano here, but it isn't working for me. It says "Kano is starting" and then rainbow screen of death.

http://berryboot.alexgoldcheidt.com/images/

Someone found a way to install Kano files onto Raspbian, but they say it's "90% working" and "kano-extras not working since last update." You could install Raspbian on the berryboot and then run this code, but not sure it would be worthwhile.

https://github.com/ric96/kano-raspbian

Answer (score 1):

The Kano OS image on BerryServer (berryboot.alexgoldcheidt.com) seems to work now. The following steps worked for me.

Download the latest Kano OS image from BerryServer: https://berryboot.alexgoldcheidt.com/search-downloads/?dl_cat=0&dl_search=kano

The image is compressed with gzip. Unzip it and then copy the .img file to a FAT32 formatted USB device.

Insert the USB device into the Raspberry Pi. Then in the Berryboot main screen hold down your mouse button over "Add OS" and select "Install from USB stick", choose the Kano OS image from the USB device and wait for the copy process, reboot the Raspberry Pi by clicking the exit button. That's it, wait for the Berryboot boot and select the new Kano OS image.